# conditionnal rendering component vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

In my vue.js app I would like to rendering some html element only if I have selected item before.

If selected item then I displayed it again into small mini card version.

**This seems to be very easy to do that with this code** :

```
<div v-if="objSelected">
    <p>test</p>
    <mini-card v-bind:item="objSelected"></mini-card>
</div>
```

But the v-if mechanism works because it display well the p tag into this. But never display the mini-card component

**Also I trying that** :

```
<mini-card v-if="objSelected" v-bind:item="objSelected"></mini-card>
```

but the result is the same...

**My mini-card component works into another component if I render this directly on the mounted component like this** :

```
<mini-card v-bind:item="obj1"></mini-card>
```

The issue seems to be dealing with dynamic rendering component.

*But why this simple dynamic rendering code doesn't work ?*

*What can I do for displaying component dynamically or after user action ?*

EDIT :

**declaration of Test component which contain mini-card (and display statically) :**

```
import MiniCard from "./mini-card"
export default 
{
    name: "Test",
    components: {MiniCard},
```

**declaration of Game component which contain mini-card (and don't displayed dynamically) :**

```
import MiniCard from "./mini-card"
export default
{
    name: "game",
    components: {MiniCard},
```

**My instance vue declaration :**

```
new Vue({
    components: { App },
    router,
    store,
    template: '<App/>'
}).$mount('#app')
```

I use the vue-router which display other component without included those into this declaration.

**Finally**

My problem become to this line for render image into component (if component call statically, this component with image run but if I call that dynamically it generate error) :

```
<img :src="require('@/assets/' + this.item.logo)" width="50" height="50" alt="logo"></img>
```

Issue say :

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './'"

Impossible to render dynamic image with vuejs ?

Comment: It should work. Can you show your Vue.js instance as well?

Comment: Are you including mini-card in the parent’s components property? Or is it defined globally?

Comment: Did you try to conditional render `<mini-card v-if="whateverCondition" v-bind:item="objSelected"></mini-card>` inside the the working component (the "Test" one) ? If it works then your issue is about how you require `MiniCard` inside `Game`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img :src="require('@/assets/' + this.item.logo)" width="50" height="50" alt="logo"></img>
```

Try something like this:

```
<img :src="`@/assets/${item.logo}`" width="50" height="50" alt="logo"></img>
```

To updating your component with dynamic data:

```js
// extend and register in one step
Vue.component('mini-card', {
   //Props camelCase in JS
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  // show your data
  template: `<strong>{{ item.name }}</strong>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  data: {
    selected: null,
    items: [{ name: "Water" }, { name: "Fire" }, { name: "Cold" }]
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option
      v-for="item in items"
      :value="item">
      {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  
  <mini-card :item="selected" />
</div>
```